# iOS transform and frame animation

Tags: ios, animation, transform

I want to change view frame to full screen bounds and transform to landscape.

I used UIView animation change frame and view's transform.

```c
- (void)enterFullScreen {
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds));
  self.originFrame = self.presentView.frame;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:ZXYAnimationDuration animations:^{
    self.presentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    self.presentView.frame = frame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
}

- (void)exitFullScreen {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:ZXYAnimationDuration animations:^{
    self.presentView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.presentView.frame = self.originFrame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
}
```

I expect the view rotate to landscape and full screen, but seems rotate error.
[image]

Comment: don't modify frame instead use Autolayout constraints

Comment: I find, cannot modify trasnform and frame at the same time，if I only modify frame or transform, that's work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tried it out, the answer is, do not exchange width and heigh, just like below:

```
- (void)enterFullScreen {
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds));
  self.originFrame = self.presentView.frame;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:ZXYAnimationDuration animations:^{
    self.presentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    self.presentView.frame = frame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
}

- (void)exitFullScreen {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:ZXYAnimationDuration animations:^{
    self.presentView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.presentView.frame = self.originFrame;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
}
```